# Excel Columns copy to another sheet based on textbox value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a vba help for copy the columns b, c, & e,  based on "E" column value match from sheet1 to sheet2.  But I need to enter the "E" column value in a textbox and based on that value copy the details from sheet1 to sheet2.
Please inform sampel vba.  Please note I am not familier in excel vba.  But I am very interest to learn.  Hence please helpme.

[image: On the left is the original table, on the right is the expected result]

Comment: Welcome! Why don't you want to use [**Excel Advanced Filter**](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-advanced-filter/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the FILTER function in Excel:

[image]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759